# getHttp request using Net.Http framework, static read only field assignment problem

Tags: c#, visual-studio, httpclient

I am really struggling with this piece of code. We are trying to link our database to a part of a unity game. I am very new at C# maybe 4 weeks in, and I have been trying with the help from the API documentation to establish contact with our database. This is the piece of code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
public class GollyAPICotroller
{
    //Intstantiate once our HTTPClient avoids overloading requests
    private static readonly HttpClient client;

    //Constructor method creates a new HttpClient

    public static async Task Main()
    {
        using(client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync("http://google-auth-express-app.herokuapp.com/api/game?id=600");
                Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
                Console.WriteLine("responseBody");
            }
            catch(HTTPRequestException exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Whoops!: {0}", exception.Message);
            }//catch
        }
    }

}//class GollyAPIController
```

The errors I obtain are:

> GollyAPIController.cs(18,15): error CS0198: **A static readonly field cannot be assigned to** (except in a static constructor or a variable initializer) [C:\Users\Ivan Dewerpe\Documents\Group Project\Group Project.csproj]

and

> GollyAPIController.cs(26,19): error CS0246: **The type or namespace name 'HTTPRequestException' could not be found** (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\Ivan Dewerpe\Documents\Group Project\Group Project.csproj]

Again this might seem obvious to some of you and I hope it is, but I am very new at using VSCode as well as using C# as a programming language.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The first error means that you can not set the value of `client`.

According to the comments in your code, you should create a constructor which initializes the client.
The second error is a typo in `HTTPRequestException`. it should be `HttpRequestException`.

This could fix your problem

```
public GollyAPICotroller()
{
    client = new HttpClient();
}

public static async Task Main()
{
        try
        {
            string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync("http://google-auth-express-app.herokuapp.com/api/game?id=600");
            Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
            Console.WriteLine("responseBody");
        }
        catch(HttpRequestException exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Whoops!: {0}", exception.Message);
        }//catch
}
```